# Spaces in the filename

Tags: filesystems

Some file system cares about spaces at the beginning or end of the file or directory name?

They (file system) convert this: "/ directory /" to this "/directory/" when create a file?

English is not my native language, so I apologize any mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do care.
For instance in Linux Ext3 / Ext4:

```
   touch "file1"
   touch " file1"
   touch "file1 "
```

Will create three different files. One without spaces, other with a leading space, and the other with a trailing one.

It works just the same with directories, as Linux follows the Unix principle of [everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

Windows [filename rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) advices against using trailing spaces for files or directories, even though the underlying filesystem may support it.

Comment: Thank you! Good answer.
For those who need, I just found this link that talks about it.

http://blog.jonschneider.com/2008/03/leadingtrailing-space-characters-in.html

Comment: As an anecdote, an accountant I used to work with added a leading whitespace to name of the files she was currently working with, so that they would appear at the top of the list when opening the folder (they were ordered alphabetically by default).